# "Более, чем 50 раз..." - правильно или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Интересует оборот "более, чем пятьдесят раз". Можно ли так сказать? Понимаю, что есть альтернатива - "Более пятидесяти раз". Но первый вариант возможен в принципе или нет? А еще интересует, как правильнее написать: "Более" или "Больше"? И имеет ли это какое-то принципиальное значение. Мне слово "более" кажется "более" высокопарным.))
Вообще, больше всего смущает в обороте "более, чем 50 раз" то, что тут "более чем" разделяется запятой, а так, насколько я помню, быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Обороты "более чем" и "больше чем" употребляются при отсутствии сравнения (запятая не ставится), например:

Не стоит делать упражнение более чем пять раз подряд (более пяти раз). Цены выросли более чем в два раза.

При качественной оценке: Двести пятьдесят тысяч, это больше чем достаточно (вполне достаточно).  Ответ более чем оригинальный.

2) При наличии сравнения запятая ставится:

К сожалению, проблем обычно оказывается больше, чем радостей. На этих отделениях на одно место претендовали до 8 человек ― это даже больше, чем год назад. Есть вещи, которые утомляют человека гораздо более, чем сама работа.

3) СХОДСТВО: "Больше" и "более" синонимичны в сравнительных оборотах: "Ваш шпиц - прелестный шпиц, не более напёрстка" (Грибоедов). Или "не больше наперстка".

4) РАЗЛИЧИЕ: "Более" образует сравнительную степень прилагательных: более пологий берег. "Больше" образует сравнительную степень от "много": деревьев стало больше. Соответственно, в некоторых случаях они не заменяют друг друга.

Answer (score 1):

БОЛЬШЕ. I. сравнит. ст.
1.
к Большой (1-5 зн.). У этой машины скорость больше, чем у других моделей. Один больше другого. Б. внимания детям! //
Сильнее, в большей степени. Б. похоже на снег, чем на мел.
***2***.
к Много (1 зн.). Знает б. других. Б. всего на свете люблю музыку. Получил вдвое б. II. нареч.
***1. (с колич. сущ. и именными сочет.).
Обозначает превышение указанного количества. Метр б. аршина. Жду б. часа. Истратил б. тысячи рублей. Не видел друзей б. года. Не б.
(не превышая обозначенного предела чего-л.; приблизительно, примерно).
2. (в отрицат. предл.).
Далее, впредь; уже. Б. не плачь! Б. не буду, прости. Б. ничего не слушал. Б. здесь не живёт. //
Кроме этого, ещё. Сказать б. нечего. Прощаться б. было не с кем. * Вокруг него Вода и больше ничего! (Пушкин).***

БОЛЕЕ, сравнит. ст.; нареч.
1.
***=Больше (1-2 зн.). * Ваш шпиц - прелестный шпиц, не более напёрстка (Грибоедов).
2. (с прил. и нареч.).***
Употр. для образования сложной сравнительной степени. Тот берег б. пологий. Надо относиться к себе б. критически. Пережил б. сильное потрясение, чем прежде. < Всё более и более, в зн. частицы.